# In which project context would you use Velocity instead JPS2-EL?

Tags: jsp, velocity

We are going to start a very small web development project.
The team has experience using Velocity in the past, which was a clear option when we were working with JSP 1.2, long before 2.0... but now we have JSP-EL available.

Therefore: would you recommend to get rid of Velocity and to invest in JSP2? We are inclined to do so in order to shorten the list of dependencies, and because we *suspect* the system should be faster if we avoid Velocity's the processing time.
The learning curve seems to be not an issue., due to the similarities in the syntax.

Do you have any experiences you can share?

Comment: JSP is not faster than Velocity and comes with own dependencies. Maybe you need to provide more detailed requirements, otherwise any templating engine out there would do just fine, it is just a matter of personal taste. (I didn't downvote btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have space for learning, we will stick to JSP2.
If we have any useful insights during our experience, we'll post them here later.